# Gaussian fit on a sphere

Tags: matlab, geospatial, surface, data-fitting, spherical-coordinate

I have an array of spatial data [lat,lon,intensity] on the Earth surface. Plotting the data with `surf(lon,lat,intensity)` shows the surface is a Gaussian shaped. I want to fit a 2D Gaussian function to the data to get the center and spread (mean and variance) of the data.

It's easy to fit a [bivariate Gaussian function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) for data as [x,y,intensity]. But my data is sampled on the sphere. Latitude and longitude cannot be treated as for x and y in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Could you transform the latitude and longitude to Cartesian coordinates, and then fit your Gaussian?

Comment: hi @mikkola I'm not sure a spherical gaussian on the Earth surface will still be a gaussian function in Cartesian coordinates

Comment: I think that's true, it is not going to be Gaussian. OTOH, fitting a Gaussian on a sphere is not fully appropriate either. Maybe look into directional statistics?

Comment: I found [Kent distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_distribution) looks good. But it works for `distributions` of scattered points on the sphere, i.e., location data as [lat,lon], not data as [lat,lon,intensity].